# Расчет суммы чисел от 1 до N

Tags: java

Как найти сумму чисел от 1 до N? Например, для 5: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15

```
public static String showTotalAmount(int value) {
}
```

Comment: Что получилось у вас до сих пор?

Answer (score 5):

- Сумма чисел от `1` до `N` рассчитывается по формуле `N * (N + 1) / 2`
- Преобразовать `int` в `String` можно разными способами. Например, конкатенацией с пустой строкой

Итоговый код:

```
public static String showTotalAmount(int value)
{
    return (value * (value + 1) / 2) + "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае достаточно рассчитать сумму в цикле **for**

```
//Основной метод приложения
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int result = showTotalAmount(5);
}

public static int showTotalAmount(int value) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        result += i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

По просьбе автора дополнил метод преобразованием в строку:

```
//Основной метод приложения
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String result = showTotalAmount(5);
}

public static String showTotalAmount(int value) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        result += i;
    }
    return String.valueOf(result);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если через String?

Comment: @mark tereschenko, дополнил ответ преобразованием в строку.